# Running a script automatically just after login

Tags: scripts, automatic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

I want to run a script automatically just after my login. Please someone tell me how to do that. I tried putting path of the script into .bashrc, that did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to start applications at startup automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321/114818)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same steps as shown in the following link:
[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)

Just use the "startup applications" app and choose "Add" and add the bash script.

Remember to give your script the permissions to be executable.